# OAuth 1.0, javascript and server-to-server authentication

Tags: oauth, hello.js

We are trying to integrate a "sign in with twitter" function in our application and for this purpose we are using javascript ([hello.js](http://adodson.com/hello.js/)).

Unfortunately, twitter is using oauth 1.0 so we can't have only a javascript solution but we need to implement a server-to-server communication to sign the request. The hello.js author provided an [auth-server](https://github.com/MrSwitch/auth-server.js) implementation for demo purposes based on node.js.

In our application for the backend part we are using java and I was wondering if a java solution exists for this purpose. Could I use for instance [signpost](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/) or similar to do the job of [auth-server](https://github.com/MrSwitch/auth-server.js) ?

[UPDATE]
I tried to set the proxy used by hello.js to a mine servlet (so, instead of herokuap now I'm using a localhost servlet with oauth in the buildpath).

This servlet is doing the following:

```
            OAuthConsumer consumer = new DefaultOAuthConsumer(
                "xxxx",
                "yyyyyyyyyyy");

        OAuthProvider provider = new DefaultOAuthProvider(
                "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
                "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token",
                "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize");

        System.out.println("Fetching request token from Twitter...");

        // we do not support callbacks, thus pass OOB
        String authUrl = provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer, "http://localhost:8080/oauth1/twitter/response_server");


        URL url = new URL(authUrl);
        HttpURLConnection req = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        req.setRequestMethod("GET");

        req.connect();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(req.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder d = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null){
            d.append(line + '\n');
        }
        System.out.println(d);

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println(d);
```

and it prints the twitter login page in the hello.js popup. In this way I got some encoding error but it is quite working.

Anyway the callback url is mapped to another servlet where I should simply "sign" the request but I think I am missing something because sometimes I got the error
"The server understand the request but it is still refusing it"
but if I close all browser window it works.

However the response servlet is similar to this one

```
            OAuthConsumer consumer = new AbstractOAuthConsumer(
                "xxxxx",
                "yyyyyyyyyyy"){

            @Override
            protected HttpRequest wrap(Object arg0) {
                  return (HttpRequest)arg0;
            }

        };


    consumer.sign(request);
```

But this code does not work because I don't know how to sign a tomcat request. In oauth homepage is explained how to sign jetty and apache common http request but not the tomcat one. However, is it correct my approach ?

Comment: Hi @egeuato I'd love to hear if you can get a Java implementation running.

Comment: No, I switched to another task.

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout the spec of [node-oauth-shim](https://github.com/MrSwitch/node-oauth-shim) which is used my //auth-server and which HelloJS delivers.